# eDiscovery/Safe Harbor: Countries that might protect my customers data

Tags: data-protection

Hi I hope someone may help,

my customer is based in the european union and would like to protect its data from any eDiscovery/Safe Harbor agreements.

Is there any country left which would be the real Safe Harbor ;-) 
Well Switzerland also signed an agreement with the US, and I don't trust the North-Korean or Cuban data protection laws ... so where is a safe place?

Thanks and regards, 
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

if you are (like me) looking for PaaS hosting platforms, a safe bet is to rely on European PasS providers. 
Some examples of EU PaaS services from my researches:

- http://www.clever-cloud.com/en/ (France)
- http://www.anynines.com/ (Germany)